# How do I override the PasswordsController actions in a rails app with ActiveAdmin & Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I have a rails app that is setup to use ActiveAdmin and Devise.

I want to override the *edit* and *update* actions in the PasswordsController.
As far as I can tell, ActiveAdmin is relying on Devise's PasswordsController.

Do I need to use ActiveAdmin's method for customizing a controller / resource to do this? If so what resource is in play to "register" for the PasswordsController?

Or do I need to copy Devise's entire PasswordsController from the gem to somewhere in my app and change the actions I want to change? If so what folder would I put my copy of the Devise controller so it overrides the gem's version?

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, exactly? In what way do you want to modify it?

Comment: Well in this case I want to force a sign out before the password reset and then change the redirection after the password reset to go to a different page based on the user's role and make sure it doesn't auto sign in after the reset as well. However the question could be considered more general than this as I may want to override/change/alter other similar actions in similar controllers that are handled by both active admin and devise.

Answer (score 6):

All of the devise-related code lives in [`lib/active_admin/devise.rb`](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/19abd8f9145d5ea702d7e67936606792a77283af/lib/active_admin/devise.rb), including these controller definitions:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Devise

    class SessionsController < ::Devise::SessionsController
      include ::ActiveAdmin::Devise::Controller
    end

    class PasswordsController < ::Devise::PasswordsController
      include ::ActiveAdmin::Devise::Controller
    end

    class UnlocksController < ::Devise::UnlocksController
      include ::ActiveAdmin::Devise::Controller
    end

    class RegistrationsController < ::Devise::RegistrationsController
       include ::ActiveAdmin::Devise::Controller
    end

    class ConfirmationsController < ::Devise::ConfirmationsController
       include ::ActiveAdmin::Devise::Controller
    end

  end
end
```

You should be able to monkey-patch the `PasswordsController` to modify its behavior inside your app:

```
# config/initializers/active_admin_devise_sessions_controller.rb
class ActiveAdmin::Devise::PasswordsController

  # ...

end
```

Comment: the above solution works for me but I am only able to over ride create of sessions controller . I need to make a two step verification when logging in. and i am not able to add any new methods and render new forms. can u help?

Comment: This gives me `NameError: uninitialized constant Devise::SessionsController`

Answer (score 2):

My approach, which you can apply to any of the `ActiveAdmin::Devise` controllers, was to update the `ActiveAdmin::Devise.config` right before setting it in `devise_for` in the routes file. I needed to do a `before_action` on the `SessionsController`

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ActiveAdmin::Devise.config[:controllers][:sessions] = 'admin/sessions'

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
      
  # other routes
end
```

**app/controllers/admin/sessions_controler**

```
module Admin
  class SessionsController < ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController
    before_action :authorize, except: [:new, :create]
  end
end
```

This works for me on a Rails 6 api only app.

Comment: This no longer works, you now need something like this:
```
  devise_config = ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  devise_config[:controllers][:sessions] = "admin/sessions"

  devise_for :admin_users, devise_config
```

Comment: Worked for me at the top of my routes file. Thanks @elliotcm!! (each of these below are a new line)

`admin_devise_config = ActiveAdmin::Devise.config`
`admin_devise_config[:controllers][:sessions] = 'admin/admin_users/sessions'`
`devise_for :admin_users, admin_devise_config`

`ActiveAdmin.routes(self)`